# What is best way to cache 100k records in memory

Tags: caching

For authentication I need to cache records like username, password
Does it is feasible to cache this data ?.

Comment: memcache , ignite  ....

Answer (score 1):

A caching platform is partially specific to the platform and language you want to use, for example if you want to `c#` then something like `MemoryCache` is a good choice.

However if you are looking to cache your entire set of user data, then maybe its worth considering something different than a cache, maybe try and speed up access to your data store, look into a NoSQL store, or a memory optimized SQL Table.

Caching is great when a single item is retrieved lots of times, but not so awesome when lots of data is retrieved a very little amount (i.e a user account).